# why does the IDLE interprets and renders Tamil unicode characters improperly?

Tags: python, unicode

I have installed IDLE 3.4.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 and that works fine for English. I tried to print Tamil Unicode characters:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

print ('\u0B85')
print('\u0BA4\u0BC1')
```

Which I thought would print Tamil unicode equivalent characters `'அ 
'` `'து'`. I got the first one printed correctly but not the second one.

So I got output like this in here https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDgH7.jpg , I want to print them as I mentioned above without any crash to characters; how can I do that? The same issue exists with Python in the terminal.

After some searching I came to know that this is not a Python issue but a rendering issue. So how can I make IDLE render Unicode characters properly?

Comment: [Unable to reproduce](https://i.imgur.com/52vWeky.png) works for me

Comment: And here, albeit with 3.4.3 on Yosemite

Comment: oh! CoryKramer , I am excited that that worked for you! how can I solve it? please help me!

Comment: The point is, if we can't recreate it we can't really help you solve it.